# Facebook login progressbar on android

Tags: android, facebook

I am implement the Facebook login on android app, but the login progressbar is the old style progress bar,I want to make it to be a Material style progress bar, so I called

```
FacebookSdk.setWebDialogTheme(R.style.mydialogstyle);
```

After this, the progress bar updated to the Material style, but there is a black background behind the progress bar, how can I hide this background or make it to be a white color? Am I on the right way or Anybody can help me?

[image: As the picture shows]

Comment: post the xml of mydialogstyle to understand what you are doing in styles

Comment: Try using in your style mydialogstyle 
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: @RameshKumar, it is not related to the dialogstyle, this black ground is the window of :[FacebookActivity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookActivity/)